# What does the word very mean in the phrase "Until this very day"?

Tags: meaning

What does the word "very" mean in the phrase "Until this very day"? I always thought very is an intensifier, but it doesn't seem to be doing that here.

Comment: I would equate it to "specific", in this context.

Comment: Why don't you think it's an intensifier?  It's emphasizing that it's important that it stopped today and no sooner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to analyze lightly varying senses of adjective \*very\*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100599/how-to-analyze-lightly-varying-senses-of-adjective-very) It _is_ an intensifying usage here; 'Until this day' carries precisely the same meaning, and the version including 'very' might be paraphrased 'Until this day ... _**this** day_!'

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [Difference between "this very" and "this particular"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/113382/191178)

Answer (score 1):

**Very**

The 2nd sense found [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/very) is:

(used as an intensive emphasizing superlatives **or** **stressing identity** or oppositeness):
*the very best thing; in the very same place as before.* That is its adverb form.

As an adjective, it can mean:

3 precise; particular

5 actual

(All of the above definitions are from the same online dictionary, same page.)

Given that it is being used as an adjective in this sentence, I think the proper way to understand "very" here is to read the sentence: "To this [exact/specific/precise] day."